# Can't understand Frequency and Bandwidth

Tags: rf

I just don't get it. How bandwidth is the factor that the data rate and the capacity are based on?
Let's say we're using Amplitude Modulation. The main factor here is the ability to change the amplitude! The difference between the maximum and minimum frequency can be 0. Who cares? How can Niquist come and say that Capacity=2*B*n?
Just tell me how bandwidth states the speed and the capacity, please.
Thank you!
Oh, Please use understandable English :)

Comment: Maybe you should start by using understandable English yourself. What on earth do you mean by "The difference between the maximum and minimum frequency can be 0."?

Comment: The difference between the minimum and maximum frequency, in one word, is bandwidth. I said that the bandwidth can be zero and it won't change the speed.

Comment: Keep it simple.  Imagine a theoretical modulation where you can encode binary 1 or 0 on each cycle.  If the frequency of your carrier is 2Hz (2 cycles per second), can you send more or less data in one minute than if the carrier frequency was 2Mhz (2 million cycles per second)?

Comment: But if the bandwidth is zero, you can't change the amplitude at all. Just look at the Fourier Transform of any AM signal -- it has a nonzero bandwidth.

Comment: Thank for the answers, I'm still trying to understand.
Simon- I tried to understand that thread you linked to for years now.

Comment: The interesting point is that an AM signal has nonzero bandwidth. [This other answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/123268/3119) has an AM signal before and after low-pass filtering -- if the bandwidth were zero, the signal would pass through the low-pass filter unchanged. If you have Matlab or Octave, you should be able to reproduce these and look at the spectrum.

Comment: Maybe you're confused because in AM the carrier frequency doesn't change?  But the frequency content of the modulated signal is not just the carrier frequency as Dave T. mentioned.  You can do the math and see that fairly easily.

Comment: Okay, so from what you all say I understand that there is a change in frequency in every way of modulation, and thus the amount of available frequencies, which is the bandwidth, affects the amount of data you can send in a specific time.
Thank you all for the time! I finally can go to sleep

Comment: This was actually a huge debate in the early 1930s, until more selective "supersonic heterodyne" receivers with narrow band IF filters turned out to sound dull with "drummy" bass. Then the "sideband theory" won the day...

Comment: Guys, this may not be a well written question, but it is a very legitimate one.  The frequency content of a AM signal is unintuitive until you actually learn the math.  I remember wondering the same thing in high school.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, so far, all votes to close have been for the question being a duplicate of the earlier one, not becuase it's unclear, off-topic, or too broad.

Comment: On the other hand, by focussing on AM instead of asking about the Nyquist formula in general, it allows you to write a very clear answer compared to what I wrote on the other question.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are asking is *"Since the carrier frequency of a AM signal is always the same, and we're only changing its amplitude, not frequency, how come the bandwidth isn't 0 when modulation is applied?  No matter what we do, everything should be at the single carrier frequency."*.  That's a good question, and the answer is unintuitive until you learn about *Fourier analisys* and to think in frequency space.

It turns out that there there is non-zero frequency content in *changing* a sine wave in any way, including changing its amplitude.  The detailed proof of this goes into mathematics that you probably aren't ready for yet, since if it had been covered in class you'd already understand the answer to your question.  Instead, I'll try to give you a conceptual justification.

Let's say you have a nice fixed steady 1 kHz sine signal of ±1 V.  Suppose you add another 1 kHz sine of ±1/2 V to that.  What do you get?  Think about it a little.  The answer is not as simple as a ±1.5 V signal.  It depends on where the second signal is within its cycle relative to the first, otherwise known as its *phase relationship*.  If the two are in phase, meaning the peaks line up in time, then you do get the ±1.5 V signal.  However, if the low points of the second signal happen to line up with the high points of the first signal, you get ±1/2 V instead.  Depending on the phase relationship, you can actually get any amplitude from ±0.5 V to ±1.5 V.

Now imagine that the second signal is just a little different in frequency, let's say 1001 Hz instead of the 1000 Hz of the original signal.  Sometimes the second signal will be in phase, and you get ±1.5 V, and sometimes it will be out of phase and you get ±0.5 V.  Since the second frequency is off by 1 Hz from the first, the result go thru a full 1.5 - 0.5 - 1.5 amplitude cycle every 1 second.  Put another way, we are sortof changing the amplitude of the first signal over time.  (The reason I say sortof is because we're also messing with its phase a little, but that's a detail I want to ignore at this point).  If you were to look at the resulting signal on a scope, or even just listen to it, it would look like or sound like someone adjusting the volume control up and down every second.  In effect, we've created a AM modulated signal.

It turns out (you'll have to trust me on the math for now), that true AM modulation is actually adding a signal at 999 Hz and 1001 Hz.  That avoids messing with the phase of the 1 kHz signal that we did inadvertantly before.  The result is a 1 kHz signal that just goes up and down in amplitude with no phase shift or other artifacts.  That is exactly AM modulation.  The result is the same as you would get by passing the signal thru a volume control and having someone rotate the knob back and forth at 1 Hz.

The point is that what appears to be a single frequency going up and down in amplitude can be broken into three steady sine waves, one at the carrier frequency and one each at the carrier frequency plus and minus the modulation frequency.  And yes, it's possible with the right math to start with the AM modulated signal and derive the three steady sine waves from it.  Put another way, it doesn't matter how you actually produced the AM modulated signal, it always has the same frequency content as if it were the three steady sines added together.

Note that the faster you change the amplitude, the further the frequency distance from the carrier the added signals are.  The faster the amplitude is changed, the more bandwidth is required.  With 1 Hz modulation, we needed 2 Hz bandwidth (999 to 1001 Hz).  In general, with true AM modulation, you need a bandwidth twice of the modulation signal.  If you have a 1 MHz radio carrier that can carry voice and music up to 8 kHz, for example, then the total signal will be spread out over a frequency range from 992,000 Hz to 1,008,000 Hz.  And yes, the transmitter is actually spewing frequencies within that range into the air.  If you tuned a very narrow receiver to just 1,000,990 to 1,001,100 Hz, for example, you'd get some signal whenever the radio station was sending 990-1100 Hz tones.

I know this is a lot to take in and the whole thing sounds rather unintuitive, but go look up something called *Fourier analisys* for more information.  In electronics and most other engineering disciplines, it is very usefull to be able to think of signals not just in the time domain, but also in the frequency domain.

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood you, but adding a sine of 1000Hz to a sine of 1001Hz does not produce AM. Addition is a linear process by definition. For example adding a 1MHz signal and a 1kHz signal yields a 1MHz signal and a 1kHz signal. Modulation requires a nonlinear process, which therefore produces sidebands (at 999kHz and 1001kHz in the my example).

Comment: @akell: As I said, adding sines of 999 and 1001 Hz to a 1000 Hz signal will produce a 1 kHz AM carrier modulated at 1 Hz.  Basically that's adding the side lobes directly instead of getting them implicitly by doing the product modulation.  It comes out to the same thing.  I was trying to generate a conceptual understanding why there are side lobes in frequency space.

Comment: Superb answer, this really helped me understand. I wish I could upvote multiple times or leave a bounty, but this doesn't seem possible on a "duplicate" question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're assuming that in AM the bandwidth of the signal is zero.

It is not.

Standard AM produces sidebands at the modulating frequency as follows ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sideband)), where fc is the carrier frequency and fm is the bandwidth of the modulating frequency:
[image]